# Sql server sorting view results slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, query-optimization

I have a SQL server database-view which has lots of inner-join operations. This view works perfectly when performing select-operations. It is not very fast, but within reason.

`SELECT * FROM ViewName WHERE ItemId=1234`

However when sorting the results of this view the performance drops to an unacceptable low.

`SELECT * FROM ViewName WHERE ItemId=1234 ORDER BY CompanyName`

This seems a bit strange because when I run the same query on a temporary table

`SELECT * FROM ViewName INTO #temp WHERE ItemId=1234`

`SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY CompanyName`

This is very fast.

Is there a way to make the sorting of my view-data faster, without using the temporary-table solution? So to force the query to first do the selection, and then the sorting.

Comment: Can you post the code for your view? And the definition of the tables behind it, along with their indexes?

Comment: Do you have an index on `CompanyName`? If not, the reason it's slow is because SQL Server is having to inspect every row, and sort it accordingly. @SeanLange beat me to the DDL request. :)

Comment: What is the difference in execution plans between the slow query and the fast one?

Comment: As a first-thing-in-the-morning guess, adding the ORDER BY forces Sql Server to hold onto some locks for longer, creating contention, as well as maintain the entire result set in memory. But I haven't finished my coffee yet, so I won't attempt suggestions for fixing it, except to say that an index that matches the columns in your ORDER BY might help.

Comment: I really think the query of the view need to be optimized, it does make sense that on temp table will be faster because temp table what SQL Server do with the query is basically only filter through the where clause and order it, but throughout the view, the sql server basically would execute and check the underlying tables (your view query), and then it filter it by the where clause, and then order it. it took longer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few variants you can try, that sometimes offer better performance. The key really is to look at the execution plan when you run the query with and without the `ORDER BY`, and see what is different.

One option is to use a subquery as a derived table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ViewName 
    WHERE ItemId=1234
) AS dt
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

Another option is using common table expression, which I always prefer over derived tables if possible, because they are more readable:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ViewName 
    WHERE ItemId=1234
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

A third option is to use index hints, to force it to use the correct index. I always try to avoid this option though, because it can cause issues in the future if the data or structure change. You can read some more opinions about index hints here:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/10/index-hints-helpful-or-harmful/

Comment: Using a subquery or CTE in the way you have suggested would not make any difference to the execution plan. There was a connect item requesting a query hint to force the intermediate materialisation of a CTE/dereived table, but this has not yet been impletemented, and connect has been retired. The closest I can find is this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891374-provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materializati

Comment: Using subqueries indeed does not seem to have much effect